# ASP.NET Core DataProtection + Redis + Multiple Keys per Machine

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, antiforgerytoken, data-protection

I'm configuring a .NETCore project that will be deployed into a Farm. I followed all the recommendations for adding the DataProction, so my code is like this:

```
services.AddMvc(
            options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuditAttribute));
                    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
                    options.AddStringTrimmingProvider();
                }); 
var redis = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration.GetValue<string>("MySuperApp:RedisConnectionString"));
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("MySuperApp")
                .ProtectKeysWithDpapi(true)
                .PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");
```

In dev, where we have only a server this worked fine. We have only one entry in Redis like:
[image: Redis DEV]

But when we go to test, where we have two servers we have the following:

[image]

Additional we have the following error in the mailbox

```
Exception Type: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
Exception Message: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
Stack Trace: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)
Additional Info: An exception occurred while processing the key element ''.
```

Can someone help me with this? Are we missing some configuration on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, if we remove the option: .ProtectKeysWithDpapi(true) will work fine, all the servers use the same keys.